# Inconsistent PHP expression evaluation

Tags: php, html, expression

I have a PHP/HTML application dealing with semi-monthly payroll periods, defined by  a period, that runs from 1 to 24, and the year.  These two parameters, along with others, are captured from a database in an array, with keys 'period' and 'year'.

I have a function that returns a DateTime object representing the starting date of the payroll period, using an array object argument:

```
function tlrPeriodStartDate($tlrDate) {
$per = (int) $tlrDate['period'];
$mon = (int) ((1+$per)/2);
$year = (int) $tlrDate['year'];
$semi = (1+$per)%2;
if ($semi==0) // first half of month
    $day = 1; // starts on day one
else
    $day = 16; // starts on 16th day of month
echo $tlrDate['period'].":".$tlrDate['year'].":$per:$mon:$year:$day<br>\n"; // debugging code
return date_create("$year-$mon-$day");
}
```

This function is called from a number of places when displaying a particular page.  For some reason, the $mon variable gets the value 0 sometimes when the function is called.  sample debugging output on the resulting page looks like this:

14:2013:14:7:2013:16

14:2013:14:7:2013:16

14:2013:14:0:2013:16

This represents three calls to the function - note that the period and year are the same, but $mon is correct for the first two and 0 for the third.  The function then returns 12/16/2012 instead of the correct 7/16/2013.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. Is this absolutely 100% of the code inside the function? You didn't take out any lines to "condense" it?

Comment: `$tlrDate['period']` must be an integer from 1 ~ 24?

Comment: This is the entire function, and $tlrDate['period'] is an integer from 1 to 24.

Comment: I'm stumped. Maybe try `var_dump($per);` and `var_dump($mon);` after their values are set, just to see if there are any differences there